# Question about Terminal Prompt on Mac

Tags: terminal, command-line

I've got a question about the prompt in Mac's Terminal.

I opened Terminal and was installing GIT. I don't know anything about Unix or how to use Terminal, so please forgive my ignorance. (I know that Terminal is very powerful, though. And it's easy to screw things up!)

The prompt reads as follows:

```
Macintosh-2:~ myname$
```

What does the *Macintosh-2* stuff mean? I've never seen "Machintosh-2" in front of a Terminal prompt. Did I install GIT somewhere strange? Is there something wrong with my computer?

Comment: It is difficult to screw things up. Well, as long as you're not root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the name of your computer. Change it in *System Preferences, Sharing*. There probably was a computer with the same name on the network, so the `-2` was appended.

If you want to learn more about your prompt and how to change it, [read this article](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/21/customizing-your-bash-command-prompt/) on the SU blog.

Comment: Cool. Thanks so much for the help @Daniel Beck. I'm relaxed now.

Answer (score 1):

It is the name of your computer (which you probably set when installing the OS), shortened and hyphenated to fit UNIX host name conventions.

Not a problem.

Comment: Hi @Thilo, Thank you for the message. It's kinda weird as it's the first time that I've seen the Macintosh-2 part. While I was using my Mac yesterday, I got some alert (I can't remember the details exactly) that the localhost was already in use and that if I wanted to allow sharing, that I should go to Preferences->Sharing and allow the user to connect at Macintosh-2. I just closed the alert and didn't do anything. I wonder if that has anything to do with it. I was doing some web development at that moment and I had my web server running on my local machine. Do you think that my mac is okay?

Comment: Hi @Thilo, I ran out of space. I just wanted to give you some background. Do you still think that everything is cool with my machine? I really appreciate your help and expertise. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is wrong. `bash` will happily print *Firstname-Lastnames-Macbook-Pro* or something similar as computer name when you leave the defaults in.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: On my Machine, a computer name of "LastName FirstName's MacBook Pro" is transformed into "lastname-firstnames-macbook-pro" at the prompt. Spaces, capitalization, quotes all gone.

Comment: @Thilo Yes. That's why I wrote *similar*. It's not *shortened* though.